# How to use find_in_set() function in Codeigniter to find more than one values from the database field which was stores as comma seperated values

Tags: codeigniter

How to use find_in_set() function in Codeigniter to find more than one values from the database field which was stored as a comma seperated values

Comment: Try make your question title shorter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - Follow this before Posting your Query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MySQL function `find_in_set()` can search only for one string in a set of strings.

**This can help you**

```
$this->db->where('CONCAT(",", `columnname`, ",") REGEXP ",(val1|val2|val3),"');
```

Comment: Thanks for you help...but i have values posted from thr form also in the form of comma seperated.then how can add it to REGEXP function

Comment: `$string = str_replace(',', '|', $string);` then manage $string :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar how can i use this function, 

select * from sm_labtest_vendor where find_in_set('10018,9931',vtest_id)

Comment: @SamirMangroliya try this `$this->db->where('CONCAT(",", `vtest_id`, ",") REGEXP ",(10018|9931),"')->get('sm_labtest_vendor')->result();`